# React-Admin: How to send input values that have been auto filled from an API call?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have an input 'A' that fetches address data from an API and auto fills inputs 'B' 'C' and 'D' based on that data, but after the inputs have been filled and I try to send that form to my backend, none of those auto filled inputs are sent, just the input 'A' is sent. Furthermore, if i manually edit any of the inputs (remove a char, add a space, change the value) the ones that I edited get sent to my backend.

I'm using a reducer to store the state. The inputs that I'm using are all just normal react-admin TextInput components.

Here's the code:

```
const AutoFill = () => {
  const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [stateData, setStateData] = useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }),
    {
      cep: '      -   ',
      address: '',
      number: '',
      neighborhood: '',
      city: '',
      state: '',
    }
  );

  const FormControl = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setStateData({ [name]: value });
  };

  const SearchControl = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setStateData({ [name]: value });
    if (value && !value.includes('_')) {
      setSearching(true);
      setStateData({ state: '...' });
      setStateData({ city: '...' });
      setStateData({ neighborhood: '...' });
      setStateData({ address: '...' });
      cep(value.replace('-', '')).then(
        (result) => {
          setSearching(false);
          setError(false);
          setStateData({ state: result.state });
          setStateData({ city: result.city });
          setStateData({ neighborhood: result.neighborhood });
          setStateData({ address: result.street });
        },
        () => {
          setSearching(false);
          setError(true);
          setStateData({ state: '' });
          setStateData({ city: '' });
          setStateData({ neighborhood: '' });
          setStateData({ address: '' });
        }
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TextInput
        source="cep"
        error={error}
        value={stateData.cep}
        onChange={SearchControl}
      />
      <TextInput
        source="address"
        disabled={searching}
        value={stateData.address}
        onChange={FormControl}
      />
      <TextInput
        source="number"
        disabled={searching}
        value={stateData.number}
        onChange={FormControl}
      />
      <TextInput
        source="neighborhood"
        disabled={searching}
        value={stateData.neighborhood}
        onChange={FormControl}
      />
      <TextInput
        source="state"
        disabled={searching}
        value={stateData.state}
        onChange={FormControl}
      />
      <TextInput
        source="city"
        disabled={searching}
        value={stateData.city}
        onChange={FormControl}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export const Create = (props) => {
  return (
    <Create {...props}>
      <SimpleForm>
        <NumberInput label="Value" source="price" />
        <AutoFill />
        <RichTextInput label="Description" source="description" />
      </SimpleForm>
    </Create>
  );
};
```

Comment: Can you share the code over here?

Comment: @AnasKhurshid Yes, sure, I just edited the question, sorry for the delay!

Comment: Mr.Henriko
Please check my answer.

Comment: @podolski721 the problem is not with the state itself but with react-admin, I know that my state is updated with the values that the API returned, but the communication between the state and react-admin so I can send the data to the backend is strange.

Comment: I added my changes.please check it.

Comment: @podolski721 that's not even close to what I want... And not even what I'm asking here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to use React Final Form's FormState and Form solutions. Will use snippets of my code for example.

1) Grab the form values

```
    const formState = useFormState();
    const form = useForm();

    const {
        asset_system_parent_id: majorSystem,
        classification,
    } = formState.values;
```

2) Setup useEffect that will observe changes to a form field:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const setFluidEnd = async () => {
          DO SOMETHING!!!!!
        };

        if ('Fluid End Maintenance' === classification) {
            setFluidEnd();
        }
    }, [classification, form, notify]);
```

3) Use form.change (+ form.batch if you need to update multiple inputs)

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const setFluidEnd = async () => {
            await requestGetList('asset-systems', 'id', 'ASC', 500, {
                description: 'Fluid End',
                relationship: 'parent',
            })
                .then(res => {
                    form.change('asset_system_parent_id', res.data[0].id);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    notify(`System Assets not found`, 'warning');
                });
        };

        if ('Fluid End Maintenance' === classification) {
            setFluidEnd();
        }
    }, [classification, form, notify]);
```

You can read more about the api here: https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FormApi

Comment: Thank you! That worked beautifully for me, had to remove the reducer, onChange and values from the inputs since final form handles that.

Comment: Glad to help. One more tip: Sometimes it may be better to do this directly in an input's onChange especially if you want to do something on clearing a value: `onChange={value => !value && form.change('quantity', 0.01)}`

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code.
-index.js file

```
import axios from "axios";

export const setInputValue = (data) => {
    return axios.get(`https://www.example.com/profile`)
        .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
        });
};
```

-component.js

```
 return setInputValue(value).then(() => {
           this.setState(() => ({
                loading: false
            }));
        });

...
render(){
return (
...
   <input type="text" onClick={e => this.onClick(e)} value={this.state.value}/>
..
)}
...
```

- react-admin.php

```
...
public function setInputValue(value)
    {
        try {
            $user->set(value);
            return response()->json(["result" => "successfully!"]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return getErrorResponse($e);
        }
    }
```